# Testing Perl on Windows with github actions

Tags: windows, perl, github-actions

I've released [MooseX::Extended](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Extended) to the CPAN ([github repository here](https://github.com/Ovid/moosex-extreme)).

I'm trying to set up github actions and the linux tests run just fine. However, ([Windows is failing with this error](https://github.com/Ovid/moosex-extreme/runs/6578519329?check_suite_focus=true#step:6:381):

```
Configuring true-v1.0.2 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Function::Parameters
--> Working on Function::Parameters
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MA/MAUKE/Function-Parameters-2.001003.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Function-Parameters-2.001003 ... OK
Building Function-Parameters-2.001003 ... OK
Successfully installed Function-Parameters-2.001003
! Installing true failed. See C:\Users\RUNNER~1\.cpanm\work\1653412748.5640\build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
Building true-v1.0.2 ... FAIL
```

Of course, I can't see that `C:\Users\RUNNER~1\.cpanm\work\1653412748.5640\build.log` to understand what happened.

The `true` module [passes its CPAN testers tests on Windows](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=true+v1.0.2), so I don't know why it's failing in Github Actions.

My workflow looks like this:

```yaml
# Hacked from https://github.com/skaji/perl-github-actions-sample/blob/master/.github/workflows/windows.yml
# See also: https://perlmaven.com/github-actions-running-on-3-operating-systems
name: windows

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
    tags-ignore:
      - '*'
  pull_request:

jobs:
  perl:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        perl-version:
          - '5.20'
          - '5.22'
          - '5.24'
          - '5.26'
          - '5.28'
          - '5.30'
          - '5.32'
          - '5.34'
          - 'latest'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Perl
        run: |
          choco install strawberryperl
          echo "C:\strawberry\c\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
      - name: perl -V
        run: perl -V
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: curl -sL https://git.io/cpm | perl - install -g --show-build-log-on-failure Dist::Zilla
      - name: Run Tests
        run: |
          dzil authordeps --missing | cpanm --notest
          dzil listdeps --author --missing | cpanm --notest
          dzil test --author --release
```

[This is the PR to which the actions are attached](https://github.com/Ovid/moosex-extreme/pull/13).

I don't have access to a Windows box. Does anyone know what I missed?

Comment: *"I can't see that C:\Users\RUNNER~1\.cpanm\work\1653412748.5640\build.log to understand what happened"* : Can you try run `cpanm` with verbose switch: `dzil authordeps --missing | cpanm -v --notest`. I think that will provide more detailed information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since GitHub Actions/Workflows uses a container for Windows that already has a version of [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html) pre-installed, it will not allow you to install any other version. You cannot remove the version of Perl that's pre-installed, and removing/installing a new one via Chocolatey is also next to impossible. If you re-install the version from Chocolatey that's already on the container, it seems to allow this, but it's basically a `NOOP` for you as a test setup.

The container also has MinGW installed; this can be bad for us as well. Having MinGW installed separately prevents XS modules from building (whether they be a dependency or if your own module is an XS module). Granted, this only happens if MinGW appears in the `PATH` ahead of your Perl install, but when you remove one Perl and add another, you're going to hit this problem.

To get around this, the best course of action is to remove the currently installed version of Perl from the `PATH` environment variable, along with their currently installed version of MinGW. Once both are safely out of the PATH, you can install a Portable[1] [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html), put that Perl's paths in your `PATH` and begin testing with a fresh install of Strawberry Perl. GitHub recently broke our ability to do this directly in an Action YAML file.

That all sounds like a big headache, but it's really not. There's an Action available to us for this very purpose: [actions-setup-perl](https://github.com/shogo82148/actions-setup-perl). With this action you can easily test using any version of Perl you like. So, if you're hearing someone report a bug on Perl v5.26 on Windows, you can now add that to your matrix and test easily without the need for any back-and-forth from the user:

```yaml
name: windows
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
    tags-ignore:
      - '*'
  pull_request:
jobs:
  perl:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: true
      matrix:
        perl-version:
          - '5.30'
          # - '5.28'
          # - '5.26'
          # - '5.24'
          # - '5.22'
          # - '5.20'
          # - '5.18'
          # - '5.16'
          - '5.14'
    steps:
      - name: Setup perl
        uses: shogo82148/actions-setup-perl@v1
        with:
          perl-version: ${{ matrix.perl-version }}
          distribution: strawberry
      - name: Set git to use LF
        run: |
          git config --global core.autocrlf false
          git config --global core.eol lf
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: perl -V
        run: perl -V
      - name: Ensure we have a working toolchain
        run: cpanm ExtUtils::Manifest App::cpanminus
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: cpanm -n --installdeps .
      - name: Run Tests
        run: cpanm --test-only -v .
```

`[1]` Portable versions of Strawberry Perl are zipped up, already compiled versions of Perl that do not require you to run an installer on Windows. This means that no heightened privileges are required, etc. You just unzip the archive in the directory you want to run Perl from, then add the relevant paths to Perl in your `$env:PATH` variable. It takes away any annoyances of build irregularities, etc. I've found it to be the most sane way to test on Windows.

Comment: I wonder how I know what the relevant path to Perl is.